# Tag synonym request: lord-of-the-rings -> the-lord-of-the-rings

Tags: support, retag-request

Can we please have [the-lord-of-the-rings](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-lord-of-the-rings) and [lord-of-the-rings](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings) as synonyms? In SFF, [the latter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings) is popular and in [Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-lord-of-the-rings), the former. I think both are likely to be used here. (I personally prefer the former as the master, but either would do.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I mod-renamed the [lord-of-the-rings](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings) tags to [the-lord-of-the-rings](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-lord-of-the-rings).

But a tag synonym isn't necessary here. This is a short-term problem because the reputation to create *new* tags is lowered to private-beta/boot-strapping levels. Once the site gets going, it becomes much harder to inadvertently create new tags where a simple variation already exists. Text completion helps guide users to the *correct* usage:

<kbd>l</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> → <kbd>the-lord-of-the-rings</kbd>

Synonyms were intended to link two completely separate words meaning essentially the same thing (think 'car' vs 'auto'). Everything else only bulks up the tag listings needlesslly.

Answer (score 5):

Yes we should and now we have question with both the tags too.

But it's better to keep [the-lord-of-the-rings](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-lord-of-the-rings) as the primary tag as it's part of official name too.