# Should we merge Homer tags?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

We have both [odyssey](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odyssey) and [the-odyssey](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-odyssey). We have both [the-iliad](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-iliad) and [illiad](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/illiad). Should we merge and synonymise these? If so, which one should be our final destination tag?

Answer (score -1):

We should merge [odyssey](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odyssey) into [the-odyssey](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-odyssey) and synonymise [odyssey](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odyssey) in favor of [the-odyssey](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-odyssey), per [this consensus](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/tag-name-conventions-to-the-or-not-to-the). We should merge [illiad](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/illiad) into [the-iliad](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-iliad), as the first is a misspelling of the second. However, we should not synonymize because it is a misspelling, but we should synonymise [iliad](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iliad) in favor of [the-iliad](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-iliad).

Comment: No point in synonymising: as mentioned in the very post you link to, typing `odyssey` into the tag box would catch the [tag:the-odyssey] tag anyway.

Comment: @Randal'Thor My main point for posting this was that I am not able to merge them.

Comment: Yes you are; I just did.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Really, how?

Comment: By editing the two questions which used the incorrect tags.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Oh, is there a way to preserve the tag wiki from the incorrect one?

Comment: Just copy it over (as I see you've already done anyway).