# Rename [hitchhikers-guide-galaxy] to [the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The tag character limit [was recently lifted to 35 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags/299490#299490). With that room now available, I'd like to suggest that we rename [hitchhikers-guide-galaxy](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitchhikers-guide-galaxy) (24 characters) to [the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy), sitting at the exact edge of the limit with 35 characters exactly. This way it fits the book title! It'll work, don't panic.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why this needs a meta post? It's just one question; go ahead and edit it. If people object, it's very easy to roll it back.

Comment: Or was this a synonym thing that I just didn't see?

Comment: @Hamlet Force of habit, didn't even occur to me I could've renamed it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - I've renamed it to [the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy), in accordance with [Tag name conventions: to the or not to the?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/273/58).